# additional codes needed in script

Tags: javascript, php

I have this

```
function changeLink(link) {
     var value1 = document.getElementsByName('find')[0].value;
     var value2 = document.getElementsByName('field')[0].value;

     parent.iframe_a2.location=link + "?find=" + value1
}
```

In that I can get the value of `name="find"` in `select2WSearch.php` the only problem is i also  need `name="field"` value in `select2WSearch.php` just additional codes will do help pls in

```
  parent.iframe_a2.location=link + "?find=" + value1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please restructure this into the format of a question so that we might answer it.

Comment: can you share the code in `select2WSearch.php`?

Comment: Are you looking for this:

parent.iframe_a2.location=link + "?find=" + value1  + '&field=' + value2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I think:
Replace the other line with this one.

```
parent.iframe_a2.location=link + "?find=" + value1 + "&field=" + value2
```